# How to calculate the eigenvalues of a matrix over a finite field?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, finite-fields

Is there any way to calculate the eigenvalues (or eigen vectors) of a matrix over a finite field rather than brute force? I created $5\times5$ matrices over $\mathbb{F}_5$ and calculated eigenvalues. I just tried all the $5 \times 1$ vectors over $\mathbb{F}_5$ (there are only $5^5$ $5\times1$ vectors).

Some have eigenvalues and the others do not (or I wasn't able to find eigenvalues).
The following matrix $A$ does not have an eigenvalue, for example. The rank is 5 and it has the inverse matrix too... Do some matrices over a finite field have no eigenvalue? If it's not a finite field, it has 5 eigenvalues in $\mathbb{C}$...

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
2&1&1&1&4\\
2&4&2&4&1\\
1&0&1&4&0\\
4&4&4&3&2\\
2&0&0&4&1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: so you want to find eigenvalues without calculating the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: Real-valued matrices sometimes have eigenvalues in $\Bbb R$, and sometimes in an algebraic extension of $\Bbb R$; it just so happens that the only nontrivial algebraic extension of $\Bbb R$ is $\Bbb C$, so all the eigenvalues can be found there. By the same token, matrices over a finite field sometimes have eigenvalues in that field, and sometimes in an algebraic extension of that finite field; thus all eigenvalues can be found in finite fields (perhaps larger ones).

Comment: thank you. I didn't think about using characteristic polynomial... just used it and found the characteristic polynomial doesn't have a root in $\mathbb{F}_5$.. hmm so A does not have an eigenvalue in there... is there any direction on how to extend $\mathbb{F}_5$ so that A has eigenvalue?

Comment: The eigenvalues are there, but hiding in field extensions.

Comment: Thank you... I am checking $GF(5^5$ and see if A has an eigenvalue in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of that matrix factors over $GF(5)$ as
$$
\chi_A(x)=\det(xI_5-A)=\left(x^2+2 x+4\right) \left(x^3+2 x^2+2 x+2\right).
$$
Therefore the matrix $A$ has two eigenvalues in $GF(5^2)$ and three eigenvalues in $GF(5^3)$. From the first factor
$$x^2+2x+4=(x+1)^2-2$$
we see that $-1\pm\sqrt2$ are the eigenvalues in $GF(5^2)=GF(5)(\sqrt2)$.

If you want a single field to contain them all you need to go to $GF(5^6)$.

Comment: Thank you. After I read your answer, I searched $GF(5^2)$ and found two eigenvalues (6 and 22) with multiple eigenvectors, which are $-1+\sqrt{2}$ and $-1-\sqrt{2}$...  will continue on searching $GF(5^3)$ and $GF(5^6)$. Thank you very much.

Comment: In $GF(5^3)$ 33,55, and 65 are the eigenvalues and each has 124 eigenvectors. In $GF(5^2)$, 6 and 22, each of which has 24 eigenvectors. I guess the number of eigenvectors is the order - 1.  It seems that it has two eigenvalues in $GF(5^4)$ (159 and 624) too..

Comment: I don't understand your notation. There are no canonical elements called $6$, $22$ etc in the extension fields. Some numberings can be introduced (and are, indeed, useful in computer implementations), but I cannot decipher those. Because $GF(5^2)$ is a subfield of $GF(5^4)$, the eigenvalues in $GF(5^2)$ also appear in $GF(5^4)$, but apparently $-1\pm\sqrt2$ get a different number in $GF(5^4)$ by whatever program you are using. Do check what your program calls $-1+\sqrt2$ in $GF(5^4)$ to see that the eigenvalues in $GF(5^4)$ are the same as the eigenvalues in $GF(5^2)$!

Comment: Anyway, all the eigenvalues have multiplicity one, so the eigenspaces are 1-dimensional (over whichever field you happen to look at them).